# Match double quotes that doesn't have a preceding escape character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that has some double quotes escaped and some not escaped. 
Like this,

```
var a = "abcd\\\"\""
a = a.replace(/\[^\\\]\"/g, 'bcde')
console.log(a)
```

The string translates to literal, `abcd\""`.
Now, i am using the above regex to replace non-escaped double quotes. 
And only the second double quote must be replaced.

The result must look like this,

```
abcd\"bcde
```

But it is returing the same original string, `abcd\""` with no replacement.

Comment: Try `replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, '$1')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use capture group here:

```
a = a.replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, '$1bcde')
//=> abcd\"bcde
```

Answer (score 3):

A negative lookbehind is what you want. However it is not supported in the Regex' JS flavor.

You can achieve this by processing the result in two steps:

```
var a = "abcd\\\"\"";
console.log(a);
var result = a.replace(/(\\)?"/g, function($0,$1){ return $1?$0:'{REMOVED}';});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks goita... what values, $0, $1 get in this case?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar They're `match` and `p1` in [this table of arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)